# Looping over csv files

Tags: r, loops, csv

So, I created a list a of csv files:

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
```

Then I separated them into two different lists:

```
tbl1 <- tbl[c(1,3:7,10:12,14:18,20)]
tbl2 <- tbl[c(2,19,8:9,13)]
```

Then loaded them:

```
list_of_data1 = lapply(tbl1, read.csv)
list_of_data2 = lapply(tbl2, read.csv)
```

And now I want to create a master file. I just want to select some data from each of csv file and store it in one table. To do that I created such loop:

```
gdata1 = lapply(list_of_data1,function(x) x[3:nrow(x),10:13])

for( i in 1:length(list_of_data1)){
rownames(gdata1[[i]]) = list_of_data1[[i]][3:nrow(list_of_data1[[i]]),1]
}
tmp = lapply(gdata1,function(x) matrix(as.numeric(x),ncol=4))


final.table1=c()
for(i in 1:length(gnames)){
      print(i)
      tmp=gnames[i]
      f1 = function(x) {x[tmp,]}
      tmp2 = lapply(gdata1,f1)
      tmp3 = c()
      for(j in 1:length(tmp2)){
          tmp3=rbind(tmp3,tmp2[[j]])
      }
      tmp4 = as.vector(t(tmp3))
      final.table1 = rbind(final.table1,tmp4)
}

rownames(final.table1) = gnames
```

I created two different lists of data because in first one `list_of_data1` there are four interesting columns for me (10:13) and in the other one `list_of_data2` there are only 3 columns (10:12). I want to put all of the data in one table. Is there any way to do it in one loop ?

I have an idea how to solve that problem. I may create a new loop for `list_of_data2`and after that bind both of them using `cbind`. I want to do it in more elegant way so that's why I came here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into `do.call` , you can rbind your first list of tables and then rbind your second list of tables and then cbind as you stated. Below a trivial use of do.call

```
#creating a list of tables that we are interested in appending 
#together in one master dataframe
ts<-lapply(c(1,2,3),function(x) data.frame(c1=rep(c("a","b"),2),c2=(1:4)*x,c3=rnorm(4)))

#you could of course subset ts to the set of columns 
#you find of interest ts[,colsOfInterest]
master<-do.call(rbind,ts)
```

After seeing your complication of various row/columns of interest in each file, I think you could do something like this. Seems a bit hackerish but could get the job done. I assume you merge the files based on a column named id, you could of course generalize this to multiple columns etc

```
#creating a series of data frames for which we only want a subset of row/cols
> df1<-data.frame(id=1:10,val1=rnorm(10),val2=rnorm(10))
> df2<-data.frame(id=5:10,val3=rnorm(6))
> df3<-data.frame(id=1:3,val4=rnorm(3), val5=rnorm(3), val6=rnorm(3))
 #specifying which rows/cols we are interested in
 #i assume you have some way of doing this programmatically or you defined elsewhere
> colsofinterest<-list(df1=c("id","val1"),df2=c("id","val3"),df3=c("id","val5","val6"))
> rowsofinterest<-list(df1=1:5,df2=5:8,df3=2:3)
  #create a list of data frames where each has only the row/cols combination we want
> ts<-lapply(c("df1","df2","df3"), 
         function(x) get(x)[rowsofinterest[[x]],colsofinterest[[x]]])
> ts
[[1]]
  id        val1
1  1  0.24083489
2  2 -0.50140019
3  3 -0.24509033
4  4  1.41865350
5  5 -0.08123618

[[2]]
     id       val3
5     9 -0.1862852
6    10  0.5117775
NA   NA         NA
NA.1 NA         NA

[[3]]
  id      val5       val6
2  2 0.2056010 -0.6788145
3  3 0.2057397  0.8416528

 #now merge these based on a key column "id", and we want to keep all.
> final<-Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="id",all=T), ts)
> head(final)
  id        val1       val3      val5       val6
1  1  0.24083489         NA        NA         NA
2  2 -0.50140019         NA 0.2056010 -0.6788145
3  3 -0.24509033         NA 0.2057397  0.8416528
4  4  1.41865350         NA        NA         NA
5  5 -0.08123618         NA        NA         NA
6  9          NA -0.1862852        NA         NA
```

Is this what you are thinking about or did I misinterpret?

Comment: The problem is that I have a different number of rows/columns in each csv file. Some of the names are repeated and adre in different order. I don't know if do.call is able to handle such problems. That's why I decided to do that with the loop. I made a vector of names I am interested in and I try to select interesting values from each csv file and put them together in one table. I can write a new "thread" and explain everything if there is any chance that someone will help me.

Comment: ah, I see. I did not notice that nuance in your problem. So say you have a csv file 1 with 10 rows and 2 columns of interest, and another file 2 with 3 rows and 3 columns of interest. How would you go about combining those? Is there a key you plan on merging on?

Comment: Sorry for late response but I just moved to new apartment and I don't have internet connection at home, jsut at work. There are like 20 csv files, all of them have like 15-20 columns and like 3000 rows. Some of the name of rows are the same and some of them are different. I created a vector of all of the row names and now I would like to fill the table with the data from 4 columns which are in all of the csv files. So I will end with the one column of gene names and then like 80 columns of the data (4 from each csv file). That's why I want to create a loop which will collect all of the data.

Comment: If I read this correctly, it sounds to me like your gene names are what you are looking to merge on , correct? If you already know these, then why don't you create a data.frame with them as a column and then merge everything on to that following an approach as above?

Answer (score 0):

not ldplyr() functions in the same way as do.call() in JPC's answer.... I just happen to use plyr more, if you are looking at manipulating r datastructures in a vectorised way then lots of useful stuff in there.

```
library(plyr)

d1 <- ldplyr(list_of_data1, rbind)
d2 <- ldplyr(list_of_data2, rbind)
```

select cols of d1 and d2

```
d1 <- d1[,c(10:13)]
d2 <- d2[,c(10:12)]
```

final.df <- cbind(d1,d2)